# Query execution failed for dataset... Incorrect syntax near '}'

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2012, reportportal

The following error occurs when I run a report in SSRS Report Portal:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.  (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
> Incorrect syntax near '}'.

```
<DataSet Name="EstimateYear">
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>
      SELECT
      {
      } ON 0,
      {
      (
      [EstimateYear].[Year].[Year],
      ORDER
      (
      [EstimateYear].[Version].[Version],
      [EstimateYear].[Version].MEMBER_VALUE,
      ASC
      )
      )
      } ON 1
      FROM
      [Model]
      WHERE
      {
      [EstimateYear].[CurrentVersion].[1]
      }
    </CommandText>
    <rd:DesignerState>
      <QueryDefinition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AnalysisServices/QueryDefinition">
      ...
      </QueryDefinition>
    </rd:DesignerState>
  </Query>
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="Field1">
      <DataField>...</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="Field2">
      <DataField>...</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="Field3">
      <Value>=...</Value>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
</DataSet>
```

Please note: I have a custom security extension applied to the Report Server. I am running tests at the time of writing to rule out whether the is causing the error.

Can you see an error with this or have any idea where else the error might be happening?

Comment: Thats just a reference to the dataset. You'll need to look for where the dataset is defined, that might be in the same RDL or separate if it's a shared dataset. Have you tried to open the report in Visual Studio or Report Builder, it would be much easier than reading RDL files.

Comment: The Dataset runs fine running from Visual Studio or SSMS using the same underlying Data Source. The report contains multiple Datasets and all have the same error in the Report Portal.

Comment: I updated with the actual Dataset, paraphrased.